# Need to convert an Excel Sheet to its Json format in VBA

Tags: json, excel, vba, converters

Excel Sample:

[image]

Below are the sample `Json`. Would like to convert `Json` as like below.

```
{
    "student": {
        "id": "",
        "firstName": "",
        "lastName": "",
        "age": "",
        "gender": "",
        "education": {
            "degree": {
                "id":"",
                "specialization":""
            },
            "college": {
                "id": "",
                "name":"",
                "cityCode": "",
                "county":""
            }
        },
        "address": {
            "id": "",
            "streetName":"",
            "cityCode": "",
            "stateCode":"",
            "postalCode": "",
            "county":""
        }
    }
}
```

`Excel` file will have fixed 2 columns. `Rows` can be variable. Instead of students, there can be books, accounts, etc. So the code must be generalized.

Please can anyone help, I am stuck with this for the past a week.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59570414/excel-vba-create-json-payload

Comment: Thanks for commenting, but I'm not sure if it's helpful.

Comment: There exist libraries to create or parse JSON in VBA. [This](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) is only one example. Please do some research and try something on your own, so you can show your attempt before asking us.

Comment: Input data seems inconsistent - why is it "student.education"/"degree.id" but then "student.education.college"/"id" ?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I tried but not getting anywhere. I added my code to the question.

Comment: @TimWilliams That is the problem statement. student will be the root node and if it gets appended by "." then the string after "." will be the child node of student.

Comment: @VickyArora That is why I recommend to use one of the libraries instead of re-inventing the wheel and write the json from scratch. Your problem reduces to fill some arrays with data and you don't need to care about turning that into json. That makes your whole issue much easier.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I can't seem to find the logic on how to find the end of the child node so that I can add "}".

Comment: @VickyArora If you use one of the libraries you won't have this problem anymore.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I looked in to [this](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) but still the problem persists. How will I come to know the end of the node? This Library only contains ConvertToJson() which accepts variants as a parameter.

Comment: @VickyArora See my answer. You don't need to know the end of the node. You just need to create a set of nested dictionaries, that then get convertet to json with the converter.

Answer (score 3):

The following example is using this libaray (https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON)

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Example()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("JSONdata") ' define your sheet
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim Json As Dictionary
    Set Json = New Dictionary

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 2 To LastRow ' loop through all data rows (skip header)
        Dim SplittedItems() As String
        SplittedItems = Split(ws.Cells(iRow, "A").Value, ".")
        
        Dim CurrentJson As Dictionary
        Set CurrentJson = Json
        
        Dim Item As String
        
        ' create entities
        Dim i As Long
        For i = LBound(SplittedItems) To UBound(SplittedItems)
            Item = SplittedItems(i)
            If Not CurrentJson.Exists(Item) Then
                CurrentJson.Add Item, New Dictionary
            End If
            Set CurrentJson = CurrentJson(Item)
        Next i
        
        ' create fields
        If Not CurrentJson.Exists(ws.Cells(iRow, "B").Value) Then
            SplittedItems = Split(ws.Cells(iRow, "B").Value, ".")
            For i = LBound(SplittedItems) To UBound(SplittedItems)
                Item = SplittedItems(i)
                If Not CurrentJson.Exists(Item) Then
                    CurrentJson.Add Item, IIf(i = UBound(SplittedItems), vbNullString, New Dictionary)
                End If
                If Not i = UBound(SplittedItems) Then
                    Set CurrentJson = CurrentJson(Item)
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next iRow
    
    ' Convert dictionaries to JSON and print
    Debug.Print JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(Json, " ", 1)
End Sub
```

And turns this data

| Entity | Fields |
| --- | --- |
| student | id |
| student | firstName |
| student | lastName |
| student | age |
| student | gender |
| student.education | degree.id |
| student.education | degree.specification |
| student.education.college | id |
| student.education.college | name |
| student.education.college | cityCode |
| student.education.college | country |
| student.address | id |
| student.address | streetName |
| student.address | cityCode |
| student.address | stateCode |
| student.address | postalCode |
| student.address | country |

into the following JSON string

```json
{
  "student": {
   "id": "",
   "firstName": "",
   "lastName": "",
   "age": "",
   "gender": "",
   "education": {
    "degree": {
     "id": "",
     "specification": ""
    },
    "college": {
     "id": "",
     "name": "",
     "cityCode": "",
     "country": ""
    }
   },
   "address": {
    "id": "",
    "streetName": "",
    "cityCode": "",
    "stateCode": "",
    "postalCode": "",
    "country": ""
   }
  }
 }
```

---

Note that your raw data does not look consistent and I believe that this

| Entity | Fields |
| --- | --- |
| student.education | degree.id |
| student.education | degree.specification |

should actually be this

| Entity | Fields |
| --- | --- |
| student.education.degree | id |
| student.education.degree | specification |

Then the code of the field creation would simplify to

```
' create fields
If Not CurrentJson.Exists(ws.Cells(iRow, "B").Value) Then
    CurrentJson.Add Item, vbNullString
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But when I am trying to run this code, it is showing substring out of range. I imported JsonConverter.bas file. Please can you specify the steps of running this program?

Comment: @VickyArora I recommend to get the example run first (before trying real data): Start a new Excel file, import the `JSonConverter.bas` then include a reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" add the data to a worksheet named `JSONdata`. Add a new module with the code I provided and run it. That should work, as I tested it the exact same way.