# Generate json FHIR messages using excel VBA

Tags: json, excel, vba, hl7-fhir

Hello I'm looking to generate json FHIR messages based off a patient demographic CSV extract. Essentially the data I receive will be an excel file with columns containing patient demographics (i.e. first name, last name, address, DOB, etc). I need to go line by line through the excel file and generate a json FHIR message. I'm using excel VBA and would like to create a macro to do this.
Here's what I've done so far and I'm certain there must be an easier way. I've created a json FHIR message template and basically perform a find/replace.
Template would contain:

```json
{
    "use": "official",
    "family": "zLASTNAME",
    "given": [
      "zFIRSTNAME"
    ]
}
```

And then when comes to the lastname and firstname column in the excel file. I would find/replace `zLASTNAME` and `zFIRSTNAME`. I know this is by far the wrong way to do it but I don't know what the best practice is for this case.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is there some specific problem you're having with using this approach?

Comment: Would using the json module in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59586380/2193968 make it easier?

Comment: What are you trying to do with these JSON messages?  Are you putting them back into the spreadsheet, writing them to a file, or something else?

Comment: I'm sending these JSON messages to a web service which in turn is taking that information and updating a public health records system.

Comment: I'm not having any issues with my current approach but it just doesn't seem like best practice. My approach just seems elementary, the use of "find/replace".

Comment: The typical suggestion here is to use https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON for constructing JSON